# Como aceder informação especifica dentro de um View Bag Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou a fazer um projeto em que temos que criar um rede social no qual o utilizador pode postar algo. Depois de fazer o `post` tem que aparecer o que ele postou o nome e a imagem de perfil.
Para ja eu tenho isto no controlador:

```
 var posts_public = from p in db.Posts
   join e in db.Especificars on p.id_post equals e.id_post
   join pu in db.Publicar_Posts on p.id_post equals pu.id_post
   join u in db.Utilizadors on pu.id_utilizador equals u.id_utilizador
   where e.id_privacidade == 1
   select new { p.texto, u.nome, u.apelido, u.imagem_perfil };

 ViewBag.Posts = posts_public;
```

E na view tenho isto:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Posts)
   {
    @item
   }
```

A informação que aparece fica:

```
{texto = ola, nome = andre, apelido = morais, imagem perfil = /Content/Images/img2
```

Eu queria algo tipo:

```
"Imagem do utilizador aqui" André Morais

Ola
```

Mas eu não estou a conseguir aceder só por exemplo a conteúdo da imagem para poder fazer o `<img src>` e mostrar a imagem.

Comment: Este é o jeito muito errado de fazer. Por que não usa um *ViewModel* para passar a imagem para a *View*?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez e como faço isso não percebi :/

Answer (score 2):

A maneira correta de fazer isso é criando um *ViewModel* e tipando a *View* da seguinte forma:

```
var posts_public = from p in db.Posts
                   join e in db.Especificars on p.id_post equals e.id_post
                   join pu in db.Publicar_Posts on p.id_post equals pu.id_post
                   join u in db.Utilizadors on pu.id_utilizador equals u.id_utilizador
                   where e.id_privacidade == 1
                   select new PostViewModel { 
                       Texto = p.texto, 
                       NomeUsuario = u.nome, 
                       Apelido = u.apelido, 
                       ImagemPerfil = u.imagem_perfil 
                   };

return View(posts_public);
```

A *View* seria assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<SeuProjeto.ViewModels.PostViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item
}
```

A *ViewModel* é uma classe simples:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public String Texto { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Apelido { get; set; }
    public String ImagemPerfil { get; set; }
}
```